# What is a computation period?

Tags: cpu, io

In my textbook `Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles (Seventh Edition)` by `William Stallings` I am confused by what the first problem (#2.1) on page 104 means by "period". Here is the problem text from page 104:

> 2.1 Suppose that we have a multiprogrammed computer in which each job has identical
>   characteristics. In one computation period, T , for a job, half the time is spent in I/O
>   and the other half in processor activity. Each job runs for a total of N periods. Assume
>   that a simple round-robin scheduling is used, and that I/O operations can overlap with
>   processor operation. Define the following quantities:
>   • Turnaround time = actual time to complete a job
>   • Throughput = average number of jobs completed per time period T
>   • Processor utilization = percentage of time that the processor is active (not waiting)
>    Compute these quantities for one, two, and four simultaneous jobs, assuming that the
>   period T is distributed in each of the following ways:
>   a. I/O first half, processor second half
>   b. I/O first and fourth quarters, processor second and third quarter

Does a period refer to the amount of time that a processor or I/O is executing before the OS switches the CPU's resources to the processor or I/O? (if the processor was executing and the I/O interrupts then it would switch to the I/O; if the I/O was waiting for data transfer then it would switch to the processor). I was just unclear as to what this question meant by a "period" since I couldn't find a definition of it in the textbook or online anywhere. (When I look up "computation period" in Google I mostly get a lot of Retirement related results).

Comment: one period could be 1 processor clock cycle, or 1 computation period could be 100 clock cycles etc...

Comment: Sounds like the time interval (aka time slice) a scheduler would allocate to each job in a round-robin scheme.

Comment: It's just a period of time. you're reading far more into that term than it actually means. I.e. for any period of computation, x,y,z happens...

Comment: @djsmiley2k no, time period T, is a specific thing.. T=1/f.  It's seconds for one clock cycle.

Comment: You've accepted a completely wrong answer, see my comments on that answer.

Comment: You're more likely to get constructive answers over on [cs.se], I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What a computation period is, would depend on the system and OS. It could either be a fixed value like a certain amount of CPU cycles or milliseconds or it could be another metric.

It doesn't matter what length a period has, the important part here is that it's the period something is active. In that question its really about whenever you understood how that specific scheduling works and what processes do when I/O etc. happens.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a computation period can be a certain amount of CPU cycles. I seriously doubt that. I've never seen any source define period as pertaining to anything more than one cycle.

Comment: Absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with OS(CPU FE Cycle obviously has nothing to do with OS), so even your first sentence is wrong, in addition to your second sentence being wrong as described above

Comment: I don't know, but here's the book - it doesn't specify what the term means anywhere. So I took it at face value. http://www.vandemataramcollege.com/app/webroot/files/notes/Operating_Systems-FY.IT.pdf

Comment: @barlop what's your definition of a cycle? A CPU cycle or a fixed time value? In addition it has to do with your OS as you might e.g. have a [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) OS in which your "cycles" aren't worth a anything as one application might just stay in control and won't be interrupted. Further more the point is that the definition of a period doesn't matter for the question. An arbitrary number you start to count from without a unit is sufficient (Cycle 0,1,2,3,4 ...). As an example Realtime systems might use different metrics.

Comment: @Seth The word "cycle" doesn't even appear on that page you linked to.  The definition used in CS is the same as the one in physics.. same as digital systems design where you have a processor see http://www.edaboard.com/thread258987.html or https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(physics)    Though in this case he includes an IO element that i'm not used to.  I think it's still one single cycle though perhaps not necessarily a processor FE cycle. but one cycle of processor and IO operation.  Time period relates to one cycle, always.

Comment: I agree with you that a period in most cases will be CPU bound. But the real point is still that it doesn't matter for the question at hand. Especially if you have a CS background you should be aware of that. It doesn't matter whenever it's based on frequency or any other metric or even what length it has. For the question the only thing that matters is that they exist and that they're uniform. That the coop article doesn't even mention cycles or periods was the point of linking it - showing that scheduling mechanism matters independent from hardware. Still feel like its wrong? Submit an edit.

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the best books I ever read, but I read it a long time ago and didn't do the exercises.. Nevertheless, I recall the terms cycle and frequency and period very frequently when I was studying CS(computer science), probably from other sources too.

Frequency is number of cycles per second. Measured in Hz (eg some GigaHertz)

Period / Time period, is seconds for a cycle.   And is the inverse of frequency. It is represented by the letter T.   Measured in s(seconds)  (eg some nanoseconds).

Cycle is an FE cycle, a fetch and execute cycle.

See here for example regarding Clock Period (represented by  T, and T=1/F)  (same thing) http://www.edaboard.com/thread258987.html

This is in physics too if you look up frequency and period and time period the terms are used with waves. An FE cycle can be depicted as a digital wave.

an example here http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/2000s/2000-01-fall/arch/figs/clock.png

I have a background in computer science but this is the same in physics, and the concept comes from physics and doesn't change anything.

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(physics)

> A Time period (denoted by 'T' ) is the time needed for one complete
>   cycle......Frequency and time
>   Period are in a reciprocal relationship that can be expressed
>   mathematically as: T = 1/f or as: f = 1/T.

In this case Stalling includes an IO element that i'm not used to. I think it's still one single cycle though perhaps not necessarily a processor FE cycle. but one cycle of processor and IO operation. Time period relates to one cycle, always.